# Why do I get "0:00 am" (en-GB) vs. "12:00 AM" (en-US) when formatting with toLocaleString() in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, datetime, format

I could not find any documentation about a *special format* of `00:00` or `12:00` for `en-GB` vs. `en-US`. I was very surprised to find `0:00 am`, where I was expecting `12:00 am`. It seems to be triggered by the **type of locale** used in **toLocaleString()**. This can be [run in JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/teritetite/1/edit?js,console).

```js
const options = { hour12: true, timeStyle: 'short' }

const midnight = new Date('2023-01-01T00:00:00'); // '00:00' (24h)    
midnight.toLocaleString('en-GB', options);        //  '0:00 am' ⛔️
midnight.toLocaleString('en-US', options);        // '12:00 AM'

const one = new Date('2023-01-01T01:00:00');      // '01:00' (24h)
one.toLocaleString('en-GB', options);             //  '1:00 am' ✅
one.toLocaleString('en-US', options);             //  '1:00 AM'

const eleven = new Date('2023-01-01T11:00:00');   // '11:00'
eleven.toLocaleString('en-GB', options);          // '11:00 am' ✅
eleven.toLocaleString('en-US', options);          // '11:00 AM'

const noon = new Date('2023-01-01T12:00:00');     // '12:00' (24h)
noon.toLocaleString('en-GB', options);            //  '0:00 pm' ⛔️
noon.toLocaleString('en-US', options);            // '12:00 PM'

const twenty3 = new Date('2023-01-01T23:00:00');  // '23:00' (24h)
twenty3.toLocaleString('en-GB', options);         // '11:00 pm' ✅
twenty3.toLocaleString('en-US', options);         // '11:00 PM'
```

Shouldn't 12h format be **consistent across the world** and *not* differ between US and UK?

- [dayjs.format()](https://day.js.org/docs/en/display/format) seem to use the US format (and never asks for a locale).
- [Date.toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) *requires* a locale to be specified.

#### Browser Differences

- MacOS 13.3/M1 + Chrome 112: ⛔️ en-GB renders differently
- MacOS 13.3/M1 + Safari 16.4: ✅ Consistent US/GB behavior

Comment: "*Shouldn't 12h format be consistent across the world and not differ between US and UK?*" not at all? Local formatting is...well, local. If you *don't* want it to be local, then don't use local. Use consistent international formatting.

Comment: It's **not** about `am` vs. `AM`, but about `0:00` (am) vs. `12:00` (AM)

Comment: `2023-01-01T23:00:00`  is not 11:00 am' ✅   it's 11:00pm,  could you correct your sniippet

Comment: @Fabian my comment wasn't about "am" vs "AM" either but about "0:00" vs "12:00". So, your clarification doesn't seem to help. Again: local formatting can vary. That's why it's local. If you do not want it to be different, then use a global format.

Comment: I can't find anything about using `0:00 am` in British English so it's indeed weird. Some sources even claim that's incorrect

Comment: Living in the UK, `'12:00 AM'` just doesn't seem right to me, so `0:00 am` seems smack on.  Maybe in the US it makes more sense.  I think that's because in the UK we mainly deal in 24hrs now,  AM / PM is used much less.

Comment: BTW, I tried the code and I never got "0:00": [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdC0s.png) and [runnable example](https://jsbin.com/teritetite/1/edit?js,console)

Comment: @Keith: Thanks for this correction! I was actually very surprised by "0:00 am" and initially thought, I was mixing 24h with 12h as `dayjs` was only using US format.

Comment: @VLAZ: I do get the listed outputs in you specific example, but only on Chrome! I added browser differences to make that more transparent.

BTW: I was expecting am/pm to be "global" (`dayjs.format()...`), but _had_ to specify a locale when using `toLocaleString()`. That got me thinking.

Comment: Formatting for particular languages *should* depend on data at the [*CLDR*](https://www.unicode.org/cldr/charts/42/index.html), however every region observes multiple formats depending on the context. Also, setting options that conflict with the chosen language are applied based on rules in ECMA-402, so it's actually a bit of a process to work out what will appear in the page. The bottom line is, if you want precise formatting, do it yourself (a library can help, hence dayjs.format doesn't care about language), don't rely in the vagaries of *toLocale\** and implementation specific behaviour.

Comment: PS. The algorithm for applying options for *toLocaleString* is described in [*ECMA-402*](https://402.ecma-international.org/9.0/#sec-initializedatetimeformat). You first need to find out what the defaults are for the particular language and regional variant you're using from the appropriate [CLDR chart](https://www.unicode.org/cldr/charts/42/verify/dates/index.html) (note that the default for English is en-us, you need to follow the [*view*](https://st.unicode.org/cldr-apps/v#/en/Gregorian/21dded0fd50ba37e) link to select other variants).